# Regras de Validação de Conta Bancária

Tags: java, c#, python, ruby

Onde consigo as regras oficiais de validação de conta bancária e dígito verificador?

Depois de muita busca no Google, só consigo encontrar regras de dez anos atrás e em fóruns, sem referência de fonte. Soube que Itaú sofreu alterações nas suas regras e imagino que o Bradesco altere em algum momento, com a aquisição do HSBC.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que informação oficial você só vai ter entrando em contato com a equipe de TI do banco ou com alguém que tenha acesso a isso (alguém que já trabalhou com bancos). Inclusive se conseguir e puder postar aqui, ajuda o próximo.

Tem também o site [www.4devs.com.br/validador_conta_bancaria][1], que valida o número de conta, então certamente eles tem o algoritmo de validação (que varia em cada banco, pelo que sei).

Comment: Obrigado, @thishinoda. Eu tinha encontrado esse site, mas não considerei olhar código fonte por acreditar que a validação era feita em _backend_. Vou dar uma conferida melhor. Se eu achar alguma resposta oficial (e não tiverem apagado minha pergunta que foi marcada como "_não parece ser sobre programação_"), eu coloco aqui sim.